# stackoverflow thinks I'm posting an image, but I'm not

Tags: support, reputation, images

I attempted to post a question on stackoverflow that had only plain text. No links, no images. Not even any *fancy* **markdown** ***markup***.

(this is problematic because I don't have enough reputation to post images)

The post was about multiresolution favicons and I mentioned ico and png files a lot.

Is the stackoverflow form verification so wonky that it notices file-type *endings* within the text and mistakes them for actual attached images?

Answer (score 4):

Oooohhh, sorry to waste your time. I'm a n00b (though I've seen and made fun of similar errors on the web a lot...).

I said "It would be great if this had a <img src="favicon.ico:16"/>-type syntax" and didn't put in gt & lt character codes.

I now corrected the mistake and posted successfully, so you can see the text (and answer the original question?) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772938/i-would-like-to-access-certain-resolution-files-within-a-multiresolution-ico-fro).

Again, sorry to waste your time, and thanks for all this meta <del>street cred</del>reputation!

Comment: You could also just escape the HTML by backticks `. Also see the markdown formatting rules on the right hand column when you enter/edit the message.